# How to Format and Organise a result of a query which is a continuos array?

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter

My Code :

```
public function get_all_posts(){

    $this->load->database();
    $sql="SELECT * FROM posts";
    $query=$this->db->query($sql);

    foreach($query->result() as $item)
    {
        foreach($item as $record)
        {
            echo $record;
        }
```

Sample Output:

```
36sss37Does it work?38394041aaaaaaa42hey43hey44qqq45hey46malibu
```

Expected Output:

```
36 sss
37 Does it work?
38
39
...
42 hey
43 hey
```

So,that explains it all,i'm just trying to organise and possibly format the output of the query. Also,is it possible to work on individual records? like,is it possible to add a comments module to each post here?

Comment: Which framework are you using? Would be good if you tell that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess the method get_all_posts() is a part of your model. It's not a good practise to use formating of the result in your model. You have to format the result in your view.

**Model**

```
public function get_all_posts(){
    $this->load->database();
    $sql="SELECT * FROM posts";
    $query=$this->db->query($sql);
    return $query->result();
}
```

**Controller**

```
$this->load->model('Your_model', 'post');
$data['posts'] = $this->post->get_all_posts();
$this->load->view('your_view', $data);
```

**View**

```
<?php foreach($posts as $post): ?>
    <h2><?php echo $post->title; ?></h2>
    <p><?php echo $post->content; ?></p>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

You can get more info from here: http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/models.html

Comment: thank you so much! that really helped. i'm just a beginner,which is why my code is so bad. I'll improve. Thanks :)

Comment: You are welcome ;) If you have any questions I'll be glad to help you. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

```
$iter = 0;    
foreach($item as $record){
         if($iter == 1){
             echo "<br />";
             $iter = 0;
         }
            echo $record;
         $iter++;
}
```

Comment: thanks. but,now it comes one below the other.
Isnt it possible to make it appear adjacent to each other?

Comment: alright,now its this way [link](http://pastebin.com/ZLGYP9sx). serial numbers are messed up.

Comment: @Arvind: Try to understand what the code is doing. Otherwise this will become a ping-pong until you have someone coded it for you as you like it. But next time when you need to do it on your own, you still don't know how.

Comment: @hakre,thanks. i'll try to improve. but,can you just tell me if there's a way to work on the individual records(posts here)?

Comment: @hakre,and sorry for my noobness,i'm just beginning to learn this.

Answer (score 0):

try using the `$item as $key=>$value`